# Tuple of tuple given on slice generation

Tags: python, python-2.7, slice, argument-unpacking

I have this code:

```
class Foo(object):
     def __getitem__(self, *args):
        print len(args), type(args)
        print args
```

This gives `args` as a tuple:

```
>>> x[1:]
1 <type 'tuple'>
(slice(1, None, None),)
```

But this gives args as a tuple of tuples:

```
>>> x[1:,2:,3:]
1 <type 'tuple'>
((slice(1, None, None), slice(2, None, None), slice(3, None, None)),)
```

Why so? I was expecting the last example to give me a tuple with three slice elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__getitem__`'s function signature is:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    # ... etc.
```

Whenever you perform item access on an object, a ***single*** argument `key` is passed to `__getitem__` (alongside the usual impled `self`). This is the case even if you write something like this:

```
obj[a,b,c]
```

The above will cause the single tuple `(a, b, c)` to be passed as the `key` argument to `__getitem__()` – it does ***not*** cause three arguments `a`, `b` and `c` to be passed.

Because a single `key` argument is always passed to `__getitem__`, the effect of [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) in your malformed function signature `__getitem__(self, *args)` is that `args` will always be a tuple containing exactly one item (the key).

In the first case, since you used slice syntax, that key is a slice:

```
 |<- slice object ->|
(slice(1, None, None),)
|<----- 1-tuple ----->|
```

In the second case – `x[1:,2:,3:]` – your ***single*** key is a tuple of 3 slice objects, which due to your malformed function signature is then wrapped in a 1-tuple:

```
  |<- slice object ->|  |<- slice object ->|  |<- slice object ->|
 |<-------------------------- 3-tuple --------------------------->|
((slice(1, None, None), slice(2, None, None), slice(3, None, None)),)
|<--------------------------- 1-tuple ----------------------------->|
```

If you change your `__getitem__` signature to the conventional `__getitem__(self, key)` form, you'll receive the tuple of three slice objects that you expect for your second example.